# Алгоритм сортировки полигонов и объектов по дальности

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть 2 проблемы. Мне нужен алгоритм сортировки полигонов и объектов по дальности (далее 1 и 2 - номера вопросов/проблем):

По условию для алгоритма дано:

1. Cписок полигонов в 3-х мерном пространстве. Пример:

```
list = [
    [[0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 5], [5, 5, 5]],
    ...
]
```

*все координаты даны в последовательности x y z.

И мне нужно отсортировать эти полигоны по дальности так так, чтобы при отрисовке они накладывались друг на друга и создавалось ощущение полноценного 3д объекта, а не рандомно нарисованных полигонов.

2. Cписок из списков таких же полигонов (список объектов) и мне нужно отсортировать эти объекты (списки полигонов) по дальности так, чтобы он накладывались друг на друга по очереди и задние не перекрывали ближние.

Помогите?

Comment: Невозможно решить задачу полностью: есть конфигурация из трёх треугольников в которой каждый треугольник накладывается поверх своего соседа.

Comment: Можно решить задачу примерно: взять из каждого полигона любую вершину и отсортировать их по расстояию.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, я уже пытался, но не получается. Я сортировал и по самой дальней координате, и по самой ближней, и по центральной, и по среднему значению тоже брал

Comment: @KirillShibalenkov Где-то вы ошиблись. Например, использовали `sorted` и не присваивали никуда результат.

Comment: а у вас все полигоны в параллельных плоскостях?

Comment: @KirillShibalenkov, открывайте новый вопрос, вставляйте туда ваш код с сортировкой и спрашивайте, почему не работает. К геометрии и рендерингу это не имеет отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот вам пример, всё же просто:

```
import numpy as np

polygons = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3, 3)).tolist()
polygons.sort(key=lambda poly: sum(z for (x,y,z) in poly))
print(polygons)
```

Я здесь сортирую по сумме координат `z` полигонов, входящих в объект.

Comment: Не получится, мне по этой формуле надо (((x1-x0)**2)+(((y1-y0)**2)+((z1-z0)**2)))**0.5

Comment: @KirillShibalenkov И с чего вы взяли, что вам нужно сортировать по длине стороны полигона??

Comment: @KirillShibalenkov Погодите, так у вас дальность от чего считается? От точки с координатами x0,y0,z0 судя по формуле? И что вам мешает подставить эту формулу в ключ сортировки в таком случае?